# How to fix hover effect for multi QFrame in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

My intention is to make a Hover effect for multiple frames at a time. For Example, Below is my code, I have three frames. Two inner frames and one outer frame. If the mouse enters where ever, that is, either in an outer frame or in the inner frames, I need a hover effect for three frames, at a time.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class Dynamic_Widgets(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Dynamic Widget")
        self.lbl = QLabel("this is text")
        self.btn = QPushButton("Button")
        self.lbl_1 = QLabel("-----------")

        self.lbl_r = QLabel("My text ")
        self.btn_r = QPushButton("Button888888")
        self.lbl_1r = QLabel(('\u2261' * 60))

        my_font_1 = QFont("Arial", 10, QFont.Bold)
        my_font_1.setLetterSpacing(QFont.AbsoluteSpacing, -6)
        self.lbl_1r.setFont(my_font_1)

        self.vbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.frame = QFrame()
        self.frame_right = QFrame()
        self.frame_all = QFrame()
        self.frame.setObjectName("ob_frame")
        self.frame_right.setObjectName("ob_frame_right")
        self.frame_all.setObjectName("ob_frame_all")
        self.frame.setProperty("type", "2")
        self.frame_right.setProperty("type", "2")
        self.frame_all.setProperty("type", "2")

        self.framebox = QVBoxLayout(self.frame)
        self.framebox_right = QVBoxLayout(self.frame_right)
        self.framebox_all = QHBoxLayout(self.frame_all)
        self.framebox_all.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.framebox_all.setSpacing(0)
        self.framebox_all.addWidget(self.frame)
        self.framebox_all.addWidget(self.frame_right)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.frame_all)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)

        self.frame.setFixedSize(100, 100)
        self.frame_right.setFixedSize(100, 100)
        self.frame_all.setFixedSize(220, 120)

        self.frame.setStyleSheet(f"QFrame#ob_frame{{background-color: lightgreen;}}")
        self.frame_right.setStyleSheet(f"QFrame#ob_frame_right{{background-color: lightgreen;}}")
        self.frame_all.setStyleSheet(f"QFrame#ob_frame_all{{background-color: green;}}")
        #self.frame_all.setStyleSheet('QFrame:hover { background: yellow; }')

        self.framebox.addWidget(self.lbl)
        self.framebox.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.framebox.addWidget(self.lbl_1)

        self.framebox_right.addWidget(self.lbl_r)
        self.framebox_right.addWidget(self.btn_r)
        self.framebox_right.addWidget(self.lbl_1r)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Dynamic_Widgets()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `self.frame_all.setStyleSheet('QFrame:hover { background: somecolor; }')`?

Comment: @musicamante, this line of code will affect only "self.frame_all" frame only.  I need to affect all frames

Comment: Then, as you should already know, please provide a [mre].

Comment: @musicamante, minimal reproducible example -- updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting individual stylesheets can be useful for very specific and relatively static styling, but, in general, it's usually better to have a centralized QSS or, at least, different QSS set for common parents.

In normal situations, a single `Class:hover` selector would suffice, but if the children have properties that need to be overridden by a change in the parent, it is necessary to install an event filter on the parent.

Considering that the event filter will match `Enter` and `Leave` events, the `hover` selector doesn't make a lot of sense anymore: we can create a "default" style sheet stored as instance attribute and set/override it depending on those events:

```py
class Dynamic_Widgets(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.frame_all_qss = '''
            QFrame#ob_frame_all {
                background-color: green;
            }
            QFrame#ob_frame {
                background-color: lightgreen;
            }
            QFrame#ob_frame_right {
                background-color: lightgreen;
            }
        '''
        self.frame_all.setStyleSheet(self.frame_all_qss)
        self.frame_all.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj == self.frame_all:
            if event.type() == event.Enter:
                res = obj.event(event)
                self.frame_all.setStyleSheet(
                    'QFrame#ob_frame_all { background: yellow; }')
                return res
            elif event.type() == event.Leave:
                res = obj.event(event)
                self.frame_all.setStyleSheet(self.frame_all_qss)
                return res
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)
```